# PHP Write data in seperate columns

Tags: php, excel, csv

When I want to put data in a CSV/Excel file it will automatically put all data in one column. This isn't very clear to read and I would like to have a single column for each data. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$data = array(
  'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
  '123,456,789',
  '"aaa","bbb"'
);
$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
  $val = explode(",", $line);
  fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

and this is what it is showing inside the CSV/excel file:

How it is now:

[image: How it is now]

And here is how it should be:

[image: How it should be]

Comment: If you want to create a proper Excel file with the format you want, try out [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) instead. What you're doing now is simply creating a CSV-file which you then open in Excel. At that point, it's up to Excel to parse the file and won't have anything to do with your code.

Comment: Show us the contents of the CSV file, open it in a notebook. You probably choose the wrong delimiter when you open the CSV file in Excel (you choose ";" instead of ",").

Comment: you need to specify coma delimiter in Excel during import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```php
<?php
$data = array(
  'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
  '123,456,789',
  '"aaa","bbb"'
);
$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
  $val = explode(",", $line);
  fputcsv($fp, $val, ";");
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `fputcsv` use semicolon as default delimiter. You can pass the delimiter you want as third parameter to `fputcsv`.

```php
$data = array(
    'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
    '123,456,789',
    '"aaa","bbb"'
);
$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val, ',');
}
fclose($fp);
```